# Jquery - Array manipulation from a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating a tag suggestions function, depending of a category. So, I have a select box with a bunch of categories, when I select a category, I want to display the sub-categories (using an array obviously) in a list. Here's what I have now:

```
<select id="categorySelect">
   <option value="6">Animal</option> //the value here is the category id
   <option value="12">Music</option>
</select>

<ul id="suggestedTags">
</ul>
```

my JSON array:

```
var tagsMakers= [
   { category: 'Animal', suggestedTags: [
        { name: 'cat'},
        { name: 'dog' },
        { name: 'rabbit'}
 ]},

 { category: 'Music', suggestedTags: [
        { name: 'rock' },
        { name: 'rap' }
   ]}
];

$("#categorySelect").change(function(){

});
```

I'm still learning array manipulations, and I don't know where to start!

In words the logic is:

When I select a category, I want to display every suggested tags for that category in the *li* below. I also want to be able to chose multiple categories, so if I select both categories, I want the suggested tags for both to show.

Anyone have a little time to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, first bind an event to the select tag, and based on the value, display the list. Also remove the JSON structure, and build a hash instead:

```
tagMakers = {'Animal': ['Cat','Dog','Rabbit'], 'Music': ['rock','rap']}
$("#categorySelect").change(function() {
   $("#suggestedTags").empty();
   $(this).find(":selected").each(function() {
   var selected = $(this).text();
   $.each(tagMakers[selected].function(i,n) {
     $("#suggestedTags").append("<li>"+n+"</li>");
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks its working fine! One thing though, what if I have 2 selected categories in the select box? The var selected wont be working, as its gonna return me something liske "animalmusic". What would you do in that case? construct another array if there are more than 2 selected ?

Comment: Edited to include provision for multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

Your array of tags doesn't have the category id, so I'll use the category name here. But, as a good practice, better if you put the category id in the categories array. Better yet if you use a object hash instead of an array.

```
function getCategoryByName(name){
    //search in array.
    for(var i = 0, len = tagsMakers.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (tagsMakers[i].category === name)
        {
            // found.
            return tagsMakers[i];
        }
    }    
    // do not exists
    return;
}

$("#categorySelect").change(function(){
    // get the selected value 
    var current = $(this).val(), 
        suggestedTags = $("#suggestedTags"),
        category;

    // we do not have the category id on 'tagsMakers', so
    // we need the category name. 
    current = $("option[value="+current+"]", this).text();

    //search in array.
    category = getCategoryByName(current);

    //populate the suggested tags
    suggestedTags.empty()
    $.each(category.suggestedTags, function(i, tag) {
        $("<li>" + tag.name + "</li>").appendTo(suggestedTags);
    });
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcZnu/

**EDIT:** If you can change your categories array by an object hash (better), so you can use the solution provided by @CupidVogel, otherwise use this, which resolve your problem as asked in your question.